# How to change the dedicated IPs to shared IP on Cpanel server

Tags: cpanel

I have a cpanel server with 4 IP addresses. 1 is shared IP and other 3 are dedicated IPs. I want to change these 3 dedicated IPs to shared IP. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I have added the domains in reseller accounts and then shared the IPs